Conjecturing the homogeneous solution of a $2^{nd}$-order constant coefficients ODE - why conjecturing a $3$ D.O.F. solution in this course?
In this video (MIT $8.02$ course titled "Electricity and Magnetism", video number $208$, taught by Pr. Peter Dourmashkin) professor solves the undriven $RLC$ circuit ODE ($2^{nd}$-order constant coefficients homogeneous ODE) by using the complex numbers formalism.
He conjectures a solution of the form $Ae^{Zt}$ where $Z\in \mathbb C$ and $A$ belong to either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ (I haven't figured out whether he meant a complex $A$ or a real $A$). In any cases, he is conjecturing a solution with $3$ or more ($4$) degrees or freedom.
My question then is why is he doing so? We know a $2^{nd}$ order ODE solution set has dimension $2$.
Edit - after watching the video until the end, I realize it was necessary to introduce three D.O.F.
I am wondering why we need to introduce $3$ D.O.F. in the conjecture, just to end up with a solution space of dimension $2$. Does this method (of introducing $3$ D.O.F. instead of $2$) has a name?

Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

The original problem is to find a real-valued solution, with two real-valued integration constants. The trick he is using is to generalize the problem to finding a complex-valued solution, with two complex-valued integration constants. This complex solution does not solve the original problem, since we needed a real-valued solution. However, since the ODE is linear, we can simply take the real part of the complex-valued solution and the integration constants, to generate a real-valued solution with two real integration constants.
In other words, the final answer does involve two real degrees of freedom. However, it turns out that it simplifies the problem to first solve the equation in a more general setting of complex-valued functions, and only "project down" to real-valued functions at the end.

Although it looks like there are 2 complex constants A and Z, which is 4 real degrees of freedom, the ODE will actually fix Z completely, and so you really only have the 2 real degrees of freedom for A in the homogeneous solution, as you expect.
